# Mobiscroll Datepicker Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, telerik, kendo-ui, mobiscroll

I'm using Kendo UI Mobile v2012.3.1114 of kendo mobile framework and mobiscroll set and cancel button not triggering every time. Sometimes it triggers but not always. If i use v2012.2.913 of kendo mobile framework it works correctly only it's slow. I think it's about css problem but i'm not sure.

Development Env.
- (Telerik Cloud IDE) Icenium Graphite v1.1
- Kendo UI Mobile Framework v2012.3.1114
- Jquery Mobile v1.8.2
- Mobiscroll v2.3.1

Here is html and javascript:

```
<input type="date" id="datePickerBeginDateExtracted"/>

$(function() {
        $('#datePickerBeginDateExtracted').scroller({
            preset: 'date',
            invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'] },
            theme: 'sense-ui',
            display: 'modal',
            mode: 'mixed',
            animate: 'swing',
            dateOrder: 'mmD ddyy'
        });    
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo UI Mobile prevents touchmove on the documentElement level by default in order to disable  native touch scrolling of the browser window. Unfortunately this affects Mobiscroll behavior. You can remove the Kendo UI Mobile event after application init using something like this:

```
$(document.documentElement).off("touchmove");
```

This will allow Mobiscroll to work but will enable native scrolling on areas where Kendo UI Mobile Scroller is not enabled (namely NavBar, TabStrip and stretched Views). You can prevent touchmove separately on them if you wish.